# SFML Sprite not displaying

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml

I recently started learning `SFML` and I am trying to display an image. The image is supposed to be displayed on the screen and be movable with arrow keys and WASD.

However, am getting a blank screen with an error F**ailed to load image "image.png"**. Reason: Unable to open file, when I display a bitmap it works. How can I fix this?

```
// ConsoleApplication8.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "SFML works!", sf::Style::Resize | sf::Style::Default);
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    sf::Vector2i position(-9,0);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("image.png", sf::IntRect(10, 10, 32, 32)))
    {
        std::cout << "Could not load image\n";
        system("pause");

    }
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    Sprite.setTexture(texture);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)) {
            Sprite.move(0.0f, -1.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) {
            Sprite.move(0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
            Sprite.move(-1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) {
            Sprite.move(1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Up)) {
            Sprite.move(0.0f, -1.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Down)) {
            Sprite.move(0.0f, 1.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left)) {
            Sprite.move(-1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Right)) {
            Sprite.move(1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        window.setPosition(position);
        window.clear();
        window.draw(Sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that image.png is in the correct place. `\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*ProjectName*\*ProjectName*`

If it is in there try and put it in the directory with the executable in it.

```
\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\*ProjectName*\Debug(or release)
```

Comment: I added the executable and when I run and debug on visual studios the image appears, but when I click on the .exe file directly I get Failed to load image "image.png".

Comment: Did you put it in the same directory to the executable?

Comment: I put the directory in the executable, but modified for my pc.